# Firebase Cloud Messaging using Messaging API

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I found there are `two` ways to send *Push Notifications*, one is via Firebase console and second using Messaging API

I have sent Push Notifications successfully via **Firebase console**, but now I would like to send Push Notifications using **Messaging API**

But **two** things, I don't have an Idea, where I can find in *Developer Console*.

```
1. Authorization:key

2. "to" :
```

I have followed [this](http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/) tutorial and here is the screenshot where I have to place these two things

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *1. Authorization:key*

The key you use for Authorization when using FCM is the **Server Key** found in your Firebase Console. Steps below.

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).
2. Then on the left-side panel, click on the **gear button** (three dots) and select **Project Settings**.
3. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

> *"to":*

This is a [payload parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) where you specify a single ***registration token***. You may also use `registration_ids` instead when sending to multiple registration tokens (max of 1000).